# gradle mlExportToFile failure unsupported auth scheme

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I am trying to export multiple xml files out of MarkLogic and into one singular file to deliver to a downstream consumer.

When running the below script...

```
gradle mlExportToFile -PexportPath=G:\Marklogic\export_header.xml -PwhereCollections=policyrequestharmonize
```

I am getting the below error...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlExportToFile'.
> unsupported auth scheme: [Basic realm=public]
```

My gradle.properties file looks like this (hostname and password not posted here for security reasons), please advise on why I am getting an auth error.

```
mlHost=<hostname>
mlAppName=data-hub-FINAL-QA
mlRestPort=8021
mlUsername=admin
mlPassword=<password>
mlContentForestsPerHost=4
mlAuth=digest
mlSimpleSsl=true
```

Answer (score 1):

"mlAuth" isn't a valid property - try "mlRestAuthentication" instead, as listed at https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Property-reference . This looks like a DHF project, and unfortunately the DHF server authentication properties end with "Auth", so there's some inconsistency.